# Lista ordenada C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct

Eu preciso fazer um trabalho com essa `struct` e que contenha inserção, busca e exclusão pelo ano e impressão. Só que eu to com dúvida no seguinte código. Eu preciso que logo após a inserção esteja ordenado.

```
struct mundial{
   int ano;
   char sede[10];
   char campeao[10];
struct mundial *prox;
};
struct mundial *inicio;
void iniciaLista (){
    inicio = NULL;
}
bool testaListaVazia (){
     return (inicio == NULL);
}
void insereLista(int dado1, char dado2, char dado3){
     struct mundial *pt;
     pt = new struct mundial;
     pt -> ano = dado1; 
     pt -> sede[10] = dado2;
     pt -> campeao[10] = dado3;
     pt -> prox = NULL;
     if(testaListaVazia()){
       inicio = pt;
     }else {
       pt -> prox = inicio;
       inicio = pt;
     }
       return 1;
}
void viewInsere(){
     int t,x;
     char sd[10];
     char cp[10];
     cout<<"\nDigite o ano:";
     cin>> t;
     cout << "\n Digite a sede:";
     cin >> sd[10];
     cout << "\nDigite o campeao:";
     cin >> cp[10];
     x = insereLista(t,sd,cp);
     if (x!=1) {
        cout<<"Erro na insercao";
     }else {
              cout<<" inserido com sucesso!";
     }
 }
```

O que eu to fazendo de errado?

Quando eu chego na sede ele encerra o programa

```
void viewInsere(){
     int t,x;
     char *sd;
     char *cp;
     cout<<"\nDigite o ano:";
     cin>> t;
     cout << "\nDigite a sede:";
     cin >> *sd;
     cout << "\nDigite o campeao:";
     cin >> *cp;
     x = insereLista(t, sd, cp);
     if (x!=1) {
        cout<<"Erro na insercao";
     }else {
              cout<<" inserido com sucesso!";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Lista ordenada com struct C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302675/lista-ordenada-com-struct-c)

Comment: O código tem várias coisas erradas, Em vez de `char dado2, char dado3` deveria ser `const char *dado2, const char *dado3`, e em vez de usar `[10]`, use ponteiros `*`

Comment: me explica melhor essa de em vez usar [10] pra usar ponteiros, não entendi muito bem

Comment: Estou escrevendo o exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem algumas coisas erradas no seu código, a **lista não ordenada** seria assim

```
struct mundial {
    int ano;
    const char* sede; //usar ponteiro em vez de array
    const char* campeao; //usar ponteiro em vez de array
    struct mundial *prox;
};

struct mundial *inicio = NULL;

bool insereLista(int dado1,const char *dado2, const char *dado3) { //usar const char*
    struct mundial *pt;
    pt = new struct mundial;
    pt->ano = dado1;
    pt->sede = dado2;
    pt->campeao = dado3;
    pt->prox = NULL;
    if (testaListaVazia()) {
        inicio = pt;
    } else {
        pt->prox = inicio;
        inicio = pt;
    }
    return true;
}

void main() {
    insereLista(2018, "Unesp", "Diogo");
    insereLista(2014, "USP", "Luiz");
    insereLista(2016, "Unicamp", "Carol");
    insereLista(2020, "Uninter", "Beatriz");
}
```

Para o código do main, o resultado seria

```
2020 - Uninter - Beatriz
2016 - Unicamp- Carol
2014 - USP- Luiz
2018 - Unesp- Diogo
```

Para a **lista ordenada** seria isso:

```
bool insereLista(int dado1,const char *dado2, const char *dado3) {
    struct mundial *pt;
    pt = new struct mundial;
    pt->ano = dado1;
    pt->sede = dado2;
    pt->campeao = dado3;
    pt->prox = NULL;

    struct mundial *leitor = inicio;
    struct mundial *anterior = nullptr;

    while (leitor != nullptr && leitor->ano < dado1) {
        anterior = leitor;
        leitor = leitor->prox;
    }

    if (leitor != nullptr) {
        if (anterior == nullptr) {
            pt->prox = inicio;
            inicio = pt;
        } else {
            anterior->prox = pt;
            pt->prox = leitor;
        }
    } else {
        if (anterior == nullptr) {
            inicio = pt;
        } else {
            anterior->prox = pt;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

O resultado seria ordenado:

```
   2014 - USP- Luiz
   2016 - Unicamp- Carol
   2018 - Unesp- Diogo
   2020 - Uninter - Beatriz
```

Para imprimir você pode fazer o seguinte (para iostream):

```
void print() {
    struct mundial *leitor = inicio;
    while (leitor != nullptr) {
        cout << leitor->ano << " - " << leitor->sede << " - " << leitor->campeao << endl;
        leitor = leitor->prox;
    }
}
```

ou (para stdafx.h)

```
void print() {
    struct mundial *leitor = inicio;
    while (leitor != nullptr) {
        printf("%d - %s - %s\n", leitor->ano, leitor->sede, leitor->campeao);
        leitor = leitor->prox;
    }
}
```

Utilizando o seu ViewInsere você poderia usar o seguinte para 4 entradas, por exemplo:

```
void viewInsere() {
    int t, x;

    char *sd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    char *cp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    std::cout << "\nDigite o ano:";
    std::cin >> t;
    std::cout << "\nDigite a sede:";
    std::cin >> sd;
    std::cout << "\nDigite o campeao:";
    std::cin >> cp;
    x = insereLista(t, sd, cp);
    if (x != 1) {
        std::cout << "Erro na insercao";
    } else {
        std::cout << " inserido com sucesso!";
    }
}

void main() {
    viewInsere();
    viewInsere();
    viewInsere();
    viewInsere();

    print();

    system("pause");
}
```

Fonte:

[Cadilag](http://portaldoprofessor.fct.unesp.br/projetos/cadilag/)

Comment: aaaaaaaaah entendi, me ajuda em mais uma coisa, como eu faria o viewInsere nesse estilo? Pq eu fiz e quando ele chega na sede, ele encerra o programa e não me pede o campeão

Comment: vou editar o viewInsere pra voce dar uma olhada

Comment: o *viewInsere* vai usar a mesma funções do *main*

Comment: Ele não passa da sede, encerra o programa

Comment: editei a pergunta com a minha função, ve se voce descobre o erro

Comment: Quando você usa ponteiro, antes de ler você precisa alocar a string

Comment: VALEEEU, AJUDOU MUITO. Consegui já fazer as outras funções